# Codeigniter 2.0.2 built-in caching is slower than 1.7.2

Tags: caching, codeigniter

I'm not sure with the built-in web page caching in CodeIgniter 2.0.2 I am using.

I just upgraded my CI version from 1.7.2
It did not have any problem at all before, the page loads really fast.

but it takes the same to load the cached page, after it is cached on CI 2.0.2
I already checked the file has been created in /application/cache folder after the page load.
It seems like it doesn't load the cache file.

Anybody has the same problem?
How can I solve this?

Comment: Is the page you're caching already static to begin with?

Comment: it's not static page, but I know after the controller function is cached, it will be static for certain set time.

Comment: Same for me, Its very slow